# drupal multi language site, language-independent front page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm working on a multilanguage site (IT(default)-EN-DE) and I want to have a language-independent "front page" with the site logo and a custom menu with three different links:

For example:

IT -> sitename.it/about
EN -> sitename.it/en/about
DE -> sitename.it/de/about

Other internal pages (history,territory,about...) use i18n module language switcher block that function well.

I my front page (sitename.it) I've placed a simple menu block with 3 items but I can select only one language.
If I switch manually (through adress bar) to "sitename.it/de" or "/en" I see only "DE" or "EN" link; but my front page (only my front page!) must be unique and not language-dependent!

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your front page language independent by making sure all the content that appears on the front page is marked as "Language Neutral" (using Content Translation).

It does not matter if the landing page will be `sitename.it/` `sitename.it/en` `sitename.it/de` cause it will show the same content (as long as all content on front page is language neutral)

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Maybe I'm not so clear in explanations (I'm italian), but the front page is set as "Language Neutral". 
My custom menu, in "Site Building" -> "blocks" -> "myMenu" -> "Multilingual setting" field, is set as "All languages" and I don't find other options to try...

I have not other content, only one custom menu and site logo